# Как сделать проверку на "целое число" / "число с точкой"?

Tags: java, android

Есть простое условие, вводим одно число(в EditText), затем второе, они между собой перемножаются, результат выводится в Toast.
Но как впихнуть условие только для целых чисел?
Чтоб при вводе чисел с десятыми или отрицательных выводилось окно, мол введите целое число.

```
 int i = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
 int i1 = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());
 int res = i*i1;
```

Comment: Если хотите препятствовать возможности ввода - используйте слушатель события ввода в поле ввода, как здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener
Но потом всё равно фильтруйте полученное значение.
Можно использовать и парсинг дробного значения из поля ввода, просто потом приводите его к целому типу.

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомился)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в XML прописать:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: Супер) спасибо)

Comment: в этой клавиатуре есть разделитель для десятичных вроде, соответственно и число дробное можно ввести. И знак минус там тоже есть.

Comment: Всё равно только целые числа можно ввести!

Answer (score 1):

Integer.parseInt() если вы передаете строку которая имеет дробную часть кинется Exception , а именно

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

То есть можете исходя из этого обрабатывать парсинг в try

```
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());
        int res = i * i1;
    }catch(NumberFormatException exc)
    {
        //Тут что вам нужно, если число с точкой 
    }
```

Ну проверить отрицательное ли число или нет , я думаю не проблема.

Можно вот так вот сделать , простой пример обработки

```
  String s = "-5";
    int i = 0;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        if(i < 0) throw new Exception("Дробное");
    }catch(NumberFormatException exc)
    {
        //если число дробное
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //если число отрицательное
        System.out.print(exc.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но именно в этом и заключается затруднение
Написать ПРАВИЛЬНО проверку для i чтоб оно не было отрицательным и дробным.

Comment: В чем именно трудность у вас возникла?

Comment: написал int i , думал что будут только целые числа вводиться
но я также могу в эмуляторе вводить и отрицательные числа(
вот не знаю как правильно прописать так, чтоб нельзя было вводить их.

Comment: Обрабатывайте событие onChange (или подобное) для поля ввода. И при обнаружении ввода символа точки, запятой или минуса (или всех кроме цифр) - просто не обновляйте состояние поля ввода.

Comment: Вот так, например: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener